# When column = ... then delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I'm trying to create a query where a row gets deleted from a table if it meets the condition.

Pseudo code: If `indexi` = 500 and `user` = 290045 then delete from table1 where `indexi` = 85 and `user` = 290045

```
user   | line_no | header | indexi |
-------+---------+--------+--------+
290045 |    0    |   0    |   500  |
290045 |    1    |   0    |    85  |
733    |    0    |   0    |    33  |
```

Expected result:

```
user   | line_no | header | indexi |
-------+---------+--------+--------+
290045 |    0    |   0    |   500  |
733    |    0    |   0    |   33   |
```

Comment: Do you actually want to `DELETE` or `SELECT` rows that don't meet the criteria? Wha thave you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I'd like to delete the row where the indexi = 85 and user = 290045, but only if somewhere in the table indexi = 500 and user = 290045. I tried using the case clause, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `exists`:

```
delete t
from mytable t
where 
    t.indexi = 85 
    and t.usr = 290045
    and exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.usr = t.usr and t1.indexi = 500)
```

Side note: `usr` is a reserved word in SQL Server, hence not a good choice for a column name.